# Updating a lookup field in a sharepoint List using SOAP in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, soap

I am trying to update a Sharepoint list using a Macro in Excel 2010. So far I have had no problems updating regular textual or numeric fields, but when it comes to lookup fields, it throws back an error 0x80002005. I am guessing that you cannot simly use an existing literal from the list but cannot for the life of me find any documentation on the appropriate syntax.

Here is my VBA code.

```
 Set ObjHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
 sURL = "http://SITE_NAME_HERE_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=UpdateListItems"

 sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" "
 sEnv = sEnv & " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"""
 sEnv = sEnv & " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <soap:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <UpdateListItems xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <listName>MYLISTNAME</listName>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <updates>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <Batch OnError=""Continue"" ListVersion=""1"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & " <Method ID=""1"" Cmd=""New"">\"


 sEnv = sEnv & " <Field Name=""MYLOOKUPFIELD"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & ""
 sEnv = sEnv & " </Field>"



 sEnv = sEnv & " </Method>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " </Batch>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " </updates>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " </UpdateListItems>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " </soap:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & " </soap:Envelope>"

 MsgBox (sEnv)

 ObjHTTP.Open "Post", sURL, True
 ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
 ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "dataType", "   xml"
 ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"

 ObjHTTP.send (sEnv)

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
 MsgBox (ObjHTTP.responseText)

 Set ObjHTTP = Nothing
 Set xmlDoc = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running [`GetListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and you will see that a lookup stores its value in an encoded format of `ID in Source List;#Value in Source List`.  For example, `ows_MyLookup="13;#MyValue"`.  You will need to pass a value in this format when calling `UpdateListItems`.

Comment: Thanks. Passing the ID and name in the format you specified did the trick. However an even easier way to get the IDs without running any SOAP protocol is to simply hover over the item in sharepoint and the id should appear towards the end of the output in the bottom left of most browsers